# How do I get my dynamic component to be inserted inside a container which is created during runtime?

Tags: angular

Loading angular components dynamically which is alright but the problem I'm facing is the container in which I'm trying to insert this dynamic component is also built at run time.

Comment: Show your effort on solving the problem.

Comment: @SteveFest: found it on stack overflow itself:                                            1) Created an instance of the ApplicationRef in the constructor                   
2)  Then the nomal: let factory=this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(arbitaryComponent);   3) const ref = factory.create(this.injector, [], val); // here the val would have reference to the dynamic HTML node in my case I'm getting it by the getElementById property//  4)  ref.instance.data = data; //pass in data to arbitaryComponent//  5) this.app.attachView(ref.hostView); //Done//